# Cannot properly restart application with bash script

Tags: c++, linux, bash, ubuntu

here's a problem that is driving me nuts. First off, I am not a Linux expert, so I might just be missing some detail.

I am trying to restart an application (namely rpi-webrtc-streamer, but that shouldn't matter) using a shell script. The reason is that when a configuration change happens I need to update the config files and restart.

The idea is to call a bash script using `system()` function and pass in the `pid` of the current process. The script should then just kill the process using the supplied `pid`, and execute it again. In theory this shouldn't be a problem...

What may be complicating it is that the process needs to run with `sudo`. Not sure if that's the case but just thought I should mention it.

Now this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "restarting streamer..."
echo "killing process with PID $1"
kill $1
# I have tried different intervals, even 10 seconds, doesn't help
sleep 2
echo "running new streamer instance"
echo "path:"
pwd
#printenv
echo "id -u"
# just to verify the script runs with sudo
id -u
./webrtc-streamer --verbose
echo "done"
```

The problem is that the application fails with the following error:

```
(direct_socket.cc:77): Failed to listen 0.0.0.0:8888.
```

... and then it shuts down. Well obviously it's not able open the port. It almost looks as if the previous instance of the app is still holding the port open. I have however tried tweaking the sleep amount of seconds in the script but that shouldn't be a problem, first I think the script will continue execution after the process is actually killed and second the process shuts down immediately anyway, I can see that from the logs.

If I however run the app immediately after the script fails from the shell that actually executed the initial app in the first place, it runs without any issues (being able to open the port). No matter how much seconds it waited in the sleep previously.

The only other thing I though of would be that the bash script might be running with different environment variables. I tried to print those but I don't see anything significant.

Also I verified that the app does not change the working directory, but that again should not be a problem as it actually launches. It then just exits after not being able to open the port.

I also tried adding `sudo` before the app execution in the script (which shouldn't be necessary AFAIK). Doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Process management can be a pain. I would recommend using an existing one such as systemd (installed by default in ubuntu) or supervisord.

Comment: Some details you should consider.  **1** If the software you are running creates a .pid file when it runs, you can check that.  **2** once you stop the software, you can check `netstat` to see if the port was freed yet.  This way you only restart once the port is free.  **3** or you can check if the process is still running (`ps`) before you go on.  **4** sudo is required if your software tries to bind on a port below 1024.  Ex. Apache.  For 8080, any user can do it.  There might be other reasons for using sudo however.  **5** send your `kill`, then loop on some condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by jordanm in the comments, I solved the problem by using *systemd*.